# UICollectionViewCells not constraining until next round of drawing

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

How can I make my UICollectionViewCells enforce their constraints immediately?

Sample Logs:
MY frame: (7.5, 57.5, 150.0, 175.0)

Container Frame: (10.0, 10.0, 154.0, 154.0)

My Frame is the frame of the collectionViewCell

Container Frame is the frame of a view constrained to be aspect 1:1, and then inset 10 from the top, left, and right.

These logs are printed out in `override func layoutSubviews()` after I make a call to `super.layoutSubviews()`, and as you can see the constraints are not being honored.  As soon as I `reloadData()` on the collectionView everything is fine, but the very first time the cell is shown everything is wonky.

The 154 comes from interface builder, that's the size the container view has there.  the 150x175 comes from the collectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

I'd share code, but this is 90% interfacebuilder.  All I'm doing in code is changing the size via the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and then changing sizes in the layoutSubviews of the cell (trying to resize things so they are the right size after the cell changes size)

Please help! this is driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

after creating the cell

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I have no idea why this works and layoutSubviews doesn't